# Can someone help me understand how this program is working

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm currently learning python as my first program. one of my assignments was make every even letter uppercase and I was stumped. I could only get half way their and then I found this program. Can someone help me understand what is going on with b = True and at the bottom where b = not b.

```
def myfunc(s):  
    r  = ' '    
    b = True    # Why is b = True?
    for c in s:
        r += c.upper() if b else c.lower
        if c.isalpha(): # I've never seen .isalpha() but I know what it does
            b = not b       # I do not understand why b = not b here.
    return r

print(word)

'WoRd'                    # If I take out .isalpha() and b = not b,
                            then every letter becomes uppercase.
```

Comment: Show us *exactly* what you don't understand from when you traced the intermediate expressions in this code. "Explain this code block to me" is out of scope for Stack Overflow: trace the execution (use a debugger or simply well-placed `print` statements) and tell us what you don't understand about one or two of those operations.

Comment: `c.lower` should be `c.lower()`.

Comment: use `print()` after every line to display values in variables and which line is executed and you will see how it work. OR run it on http://pythontutor.com/ to execute it step by step

Comment: `b = not b` changes `True` into `False` and `False` into `True` - and this `b` is used to select `.upper()` or `.lower()` - so in one loop `b` is `True` and it runs `upper()`, and in next loop `b` is `False` so it runs `lower()`, and in next loop `b` is again `True`, etc. If you use `print("b:', b)` inside `for`-loop then you will see it.

Comment: Ok now I got it, I feel stupid now lol I've been studying all day and some how I forgot that this is going to loop through every character. Thank you all for helping!

Comment: Try to run the program in http://www.pythontutor.com/ to see each step execution to help you understand and debug easily next time.

Answer (score 2):

Boy, these are some really terrible variable names. Let's try again.

```py
def alternate_case(s):
    result = ''
    should_upper = True
    for character in s:
        if should_upper:
            result += character.upper()
        else:
            result += character.lower()
        if character.isalpha():
            should_upper = not should_upper
    return result
```

Essentially: go through every character in a string. Upper case every other character, alternating when the character you just touched `isalpha` (`[a-zA-Z]`)

Comment: Minor typo - `r` in the if-else should be `result`

Comment: @DanielHao whoopsie! Thanks.